# PostgreSQL get matches from two tables and save to disk

Tags: postgresql, syntax-error

Sorry for noob question, yes, i've google Joins in sql, but i don't understand syntax error. So please help me.

I have 2 tables *eng_data_table* with *key* column 
and *get* with *get* column

I just want to get matches from get founded in eng_data_table.keyword and save it to disk. So this is

```
COPY ( SELECT * FROM "eng_data_table.key" INNER JOIN "get.get" ) TO 'founded.txt';
```

Right? No, i have a syntax error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
                                ^
```

Why he don't like it?

Answer (score 0):

When you join two tables you have to specify which fields they share in common with an ON clause. In your attempt you list those fields in the JOIN itself where only the table names belong.

Instead:

```
SELECT * FROM eng_data_table INNER JOIN get ON eng_data_table.key = get.get
```

Comment: `ERROR:  relation "eng_data_table" does not exist`   - he said this error after i wrrite `COPY (SELECT * FROM eng_data_table INNER JOIN get ON eng_data_table.key = get.get) TO 'founded.txt';`

Comment: Do you have a table by that name? Is it in whatever schema you are logging in as?

Comment: My schema name is *public*. There are 2 tables: *eng_data_table* with column *key* and *get* table with *get* column.

Comment: When i create query: **SELECT * FROM public.eng_data_table INNER JOIN public.get ON public.eng_data_table.keyword = public.get.get** he just sends to me two tables with same keyword. It's not that i want, i matches, and keywords can be **multi-word**